# Stopping Apache Rewrite Rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

Currently I'm doing something like this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$   application/views/assets/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/application/views/assets/.*

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

**However, is there a way I can remove that first RewriteCond, such as use a [L] or [S=4] somewhere so that once that first RewriteRule (the one for assets) applies, we move on and don't apply further rules?**

(BTW, this is an .htaccess file used for the KohanaPHP framework.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets
RewriteRule . - [S=10]

RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /application/views/assets/$1 [L]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* /index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* /index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Notice `S=10` at the top to skip next 10 rule if stat of REQUEST_URI matches /assets. And because of that rule I could safely removed negative rule condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/views/assets/`

To read more about option flags in mod_rewrite please see this doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

Comment: Wow, seems more work than just leaving the RewriteCond line in. However, you explained some things to me. You are the winner.